# Printing PDf issue

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation

Most of the print pdf library I ran into requires drawing tables, layouts etc. Which library can simply print the web page in pdf format without requiring too much coding? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that is free that I've located is this:

```
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/
http://www.rustyparts.com/pdf.php (PHP)
```

The best non-free solution is here:

```
http://www.html-to-pdf.net (.NET)
http://www.corda.com/java-pdf.php (Java)
```

Answer (score 1):

Free* .Net Tool:
[ABC PDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm)

> *ABCpdf is normally priced at $329. However as a special offer we'll give
>   you a free license key - all you have
>   to do is link back to our web site...

Comment: Not exactly free: "Licenses for ABCpdf .NET are $329 per installed copy"

Comment: You can get a free license if you backlink/review the product for them.